How to mock IConfiguration.GetSection("foo").get<Type>();
I am new to unit testing...
I have a class Settings.cs,
public class Settings
{
    public string Format {  get; set; }
}

and this is what the appSettings.json contains,
  "AppSettings": {
    "Format ": "/^[0-9]*$/"
  }

This is my razor class,
[Inject]
public required IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

private Settings settings = new();

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    settings = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Settings>();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

I have the following onClick event,
private void OnClick()
{
    string regExFormat = settings.Format;  ---> unit test fails because settings is null here

    //rest of the code 
}

This is how I am mocking the IConfiguration object,
Mock<Settings> mockSettings = new Mock<Settings>();

Mock<IConfiguration> mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
mockConfig.Setup(m => m.GetSection(It.IsAny<string>()).Get<Settings>()).Returns(mockSettings.Object);

How do I mock the IConfiguration object, so settings is not null? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

You can use an in-memory source. There's no real need to mock IConfiguration

The setting name is Format , with an extra space.

For such simple cases, you dont even need Mocking.
[Test]
public void ConfigurationBuilderTest()
{
    var configurationData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "AppSettings:Format", "/^[0-9]*$/" }
    };

    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddInMemoryCollection(configurationData)
        .Build();

    var settings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Settings>();
    settings.Format.Should().Be("/^[0-9]*$/");
}

and as @SELA already mentioned, you should get rid of the extra blank in your appsettings.json

Not just simple cases. As long as reloading isn't needed, there's no difference between the in-memory collection and any other source. If the settings are too many, a test settings file is a great option

Try removing the additional space in appsettings.json after Format  key. Your C# class looks OK.
 "AppSettings": {
    "Format": "/^[0-9]*$/" // Remove extra space after Format
  }

Then in your unit test mock the configuration object like the below:
var mockSettings = new Settings { Format = "/^[0-9]*$/" };
var mockConfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
mockConfig.Setup(m => m.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Settings>()).Returns(mockSettings);   
var component = new YourRazorComponent();
component.Configuration = mockConfig.Object; // DI the mocked config object      
await component.OnInitializedAsync(); // Act - Trigger initialization (feel free to remove)  
Assert.Equal("/^[0-9]*$/", component.settings.Format); // Check the output

